# Flask SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL Inheritance

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I've read like every answer on SO and googled it and used ChatGPT and I just don't seem to get a concrete answer for this.

So, I would like to take advantage of PostgreSQL's inheritance in Flask SQLAlchemy.

To make a simple example, let's say I want to have a Users table (id, username, password) and an Admins table (access_level) inhertis Users.

The closest I could get it to work is this code:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin

from website.content import db

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
        
class Admins(Users):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    access_level = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'inherits': Users,
        'inherit_condition': id == Users.id,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admins',
    }
    
    __table_args__ = {'postgresql_inherits': Users.__tablename__}
```

This is not correct because while it does create an inheritance, it's a kind of a broken one. You cannot insert into admins because it will complain there is no user with the id. The id will keep increasing every time, so it says key constrain fails for id 4,5,6 etc.

If I create an Admins table by hand, inheriting Users, this doesn't happen. Admins table created through pgAdmin does not have a primary key on id, and it correctly inserts into Users as well as Admins when I insert into Admins

However, I cannot remove the

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
```

line from the code, because if I do then python complains

```
Can't place __table_args__ on an inherited class with no table.
```

Is there really no way to achieve this in Flask SQLAlchemy?

If so, how can I achieve this through executing SQL? So that instead of creating these malfunctioning tables, a proper table would be created?

Do I have to manually type the proper SQL query and execute it before I call `db.create_all()`?

Also, in that case, what is a proper way to declare inheritance, meaning, if I do

```
x = Admins(...)
db.session.add(x)
db.session.commit()
```

it will properly insert into admins and users

PS:

It seems dropping primary key and foreign key constraint after creating via `create_all()` produces a properly working example where I can query Admins, and change their properties and save changes as usual.

Is this the right way?

PPS:

No it's not. When doing ```a = Admins(username=....) nothing is stored, and even if I create a constructor that passes kwargs on to User, nothing is saved. Using the logger, I see the query executed as follows:

```
    a = Admins(username="xxx", password = "yyy")
    db.session.add(a)
    db.session.commit()

14-May-23 15:05:11 - INFO - 2513947004160 - INSERT INTO admins (id, access_level) VALUES (%(id)s, %(access_level)s)
```